# Silverlight XNA - GraphicsDeviceManager

Tags: silverlight, xna

I am making a game in XNA but wish to port it over to Silverlight XNA. In XNA, there is a `graphics` object at class level which is of type `GraphicsDeviceManager`. In Silverlight XNA however, there is no such thing. What shall I do in this case? I need it since I am passing over stuff like ViewPort.Width etc etc to some game objects so i know where to place them.

Any help will be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. I have managed to find out that there is an equivalent in Silverlight XNA. It's called `SharedGraphicsDeviceManager`. I'm just passing over SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice.Viewport to the classes and then applying logic appropriately to the objects position.